# How to add several relativeLayout with 2 views inside programmatically?

Tags: android, layout

I took a look on stackoverflow but I can't find the answer.
I would like to add several rows (`RelativeLayout`) into the parent (`LinearLayout`). The RelativeLayout would be composed of 2 views, a `ImageView` on the left and a `TextView` on its right, both into the same row, for each item:

```
LinearLayout userLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.participant_user);
RelativeLayout rL = new RelativeLayout(context);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT)

for (Participant participant : participants) {
    TextView textView = setTextView(context, participant.getName());
    rL.addView(textView, params);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.bz_ic_default_user);
    rL.addView(imageView, params);
    userLayout.addView(rL);
}
```

It doesn't work, the first element is only displayed or the app crashed...

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a ListAdapater or RecylerView here

- https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html

You are trying to create a list of items with an unknown #. The way you are doing it, performance will be bad and you are inflating views into a linearlayout and not reusing views.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a RelativeLayout, filling it n times (one per participant) and trying to add it n times. At the very least you should create n different RelativeLayouts.

Anyway, as a rule of thumb, every time you have to crete a list ask yourself: will it contain 10 elements or 1000. If it's 10, then you can follow your approach (but I would advise to create every row inflating an xml instead od instantiating the views), if it's 1000 use a ListView (or some kind of RecyclerView), much simpler and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers stated, using a ListAdapter would probably make things work. [Here is an example](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92).

If you really want to do it your way, you should share your error log (LogCat output).

Answer (score 0):

As everyone here said, It's better to use the `RecyclerView` or the `ListView`. But if you want do it in this way for another reason, then I think that the best that you can do is:

```
        LinearLayout mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        mainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        for (Participant participant : participants) {
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, mainLayout, false);
            ((TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(participant.name);
            ((ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.photo)).setImageResource(R.drawable.photo); //BTW You can set it in the xml and avoid this
            mainLayout.addView(rowView);
        }
        setContentView(mainLayout);
```